# 2 different listviews in one expandablelistview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

I wanted to expand the login when user clicks on login and expand the register when user clicks on the register as shown in image below. I think it should be done with the expandablelistview and two lists. But can't find out how to implement it. I searched a lot but can't find the answer. found this link but no one answered this guy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601456/android-expandable-listview-two-arraylists-with-different-class-types thanks 
[image]

Comment: It looks more like a Tabbed layout and 2 ListViews (alternatively hiddend/visible)

Comment: @DerGolem but they will take equal space when in both login and register but I want to take them different space according to the view

Comment: The both seem to take full width, to me.

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks a lot you were really helpful for finding the correct and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it looks more like a simple `LinearLayout` in a `ScrollView`. It will get more complex with the adapters than simply taking some Ids and changing the visibility. You can also use fragments to scope the actions and get every process encapsulated. The animation can be achieved by the fragment transaction `FragmentTransaction#setCustomAnimations()`.